# Why is Yoneda’s lemma defined only for locally small categories

Tags: category-theory

Today a quick question on Yoneda’s lemma. My question is to know why we only define Yoneda’s lemma on locally small categories, because I have not seen where the proof does rely on the fact that we are manipulating sets and not (proper) classes, and I consequently do not see why one would restrict it this way.

Is it because it’s only used to prove other results that do really depend on the fact that sets are used ?

Thanks in advance, and have a nice day,

Max

Comment: Many thanks @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, but I am not really sure to see your point. We could easily replace Set by the category of all classes and maps between them and have a similar theorem, so why would we restrain it this way is really the question that bugs me.

Comment: There is no collection of all classes in ZFC. You are not allowed to talk about classes at all.

Comment: If you switch to some theory with universe levels, then yes, Yoneda works for arbitrarily large categories.

Comment: "We could easily replace $\textbf{Set}$ by the category of all classes and maps between them" – no. First of all there is no broad consensus about what you can do with classes, unlike for sets. With the most common formalism for classes you cannot even form collections of classes, so how you could have a category of all classes? Even in settings where you can speak of the category of all classes, it has far fewer of the nice properties of $\textbf{Set}$, so you cannot be so blasé and say it is "easy". All that said, there is good heuristic reason to believe that the Yoneda lemma will hold.

Comment: @ZhenLin I realized it 3 minutes ago. You’re completely right, the class of all classes has no meaning as such. Many many thanks !

Comment: Sorry for the bothering

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yoneda lemma and (locally) small categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092884/yoneda-lemma-and-locally-small-categories)